# NavigationLink inside List applies to HStack instead of each element

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to follow [Composing Complex Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces) guide on SwiftUI and having issues getting NavigationLink to work properly on iOS 13 beta 3 and now beta 4.

If you just download the project files and try running it, click on any of the Lake images - nothing will happen. However if you click on the header "Lakes" it'll start opening every single lake one after another which is not a behaviour anyone would expect.

Seems like NavigationLink is broken in "complex" interfaces. Is there a workaround?

I've tried making it less complex and removing HStack of List helps to get NavigationLinks somewhat to work but then I can't build the full interface like in example.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                FeaturedLandmarks(landmarks: featured)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                    CategoryRow(categoryName: key, items: self.categories[key]!)
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkList()) {
                    Text("See All")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: profileButton)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProfile) {
                ProfileHost()
            }
        }
    }


struct CategoryRow: View {
    var categoryName: String
    var items: [Landmark]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(self.categoryName)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                .padding(.top, 5)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(self.items, id: \.name) { landmark in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LandmarkDetail(
                                landmark: landmark
                            )
                        ) {
                            CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 185)
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryItem: View {
    var landmark: Landmark
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            landmark
                .image(forSize: 155)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            Text(landmark.name)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 15)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paulw11 I've added relevant parts of the code. NavigationLinks created by it are not clickable.

Comment: Looks to me like it is just broken at the moment;  Submit beta feedback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug with `NavigationLink` instances that aren't directly contained in a `List`.  If you replace the outermost `List` with a `ScrollView` and a `VStack` then the inner `NavigationLinks` work correctly:

i.e.

```
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
            VStack {
                FeaturedLandmarks(landmarks: featured)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                    CategoryRow(categoryName: key, items: self.categories[key]!)
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkList()) {
                    Text("See All")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is replacing `List` with a `ScrollView` and a `VStack` a good workaround or do you recommend waiting until it's fixed?

Comment: It's a workaround for now. List is the right approach when it is fixed.