# How to go to another view with button click

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I have a button in my code and I have a file called LogindView.swift

I cannot get the code to open another view file when clicking on the button.

Can anybody give me an example on how to do it.

In my button action I have tried to write LogindView() but i just gives me a warning.
"Result of 'LogindView' initializer is unused"

```
    Button(action: {
            // Do action
            LogindView()
        }, label: {
            //** Label text
            Text("Logind")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.all)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        })
        .background(Color.blue)
```

Comment: Funny!

I did enter some code.

But here it goes.

            Button(action: {
                    // Do action
                    LogindView()
                }, label: {
                    //** Label text
                    Text("Logind")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                })
                .background(Color.blue)

The LogindView() gives me this warning.

"Result of 'LogindView' initializer is unused"

Comment: @JensThomsen I suggest add that code to your question - here in a comment is not readable

Comment: Added code to my question.

Answer (score 74):

You essentially have 3 options to transition between views depending on your needs.

---

**First**, you can use a `NavigationView`. This will provide a back button and will allow the user to go back. Note that there are some bugs currently when you don't put the `NavigationLink` inside of a `List` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122621/3179416

```
import SwiftUI

struct MasterView: View {
        var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login View")
    }
}
```

[image: NavigationView]

---

**Second**, you can present a modal using `.sheet`. This will present a modal that appears on top of the current view but it can be dismissed by the user by dragging it down.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MasterView: View {
    @State var isModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Login") {
            self.isModal = true
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isModal, content: {
            LoginView()
        })
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login View")
    }
}
```

[image: .sheet]

---

**Third**, you can just use an `if` statement to change the current view to your Login View like so

```
import SwiftUI

struct MasterView: View {
    @State var showLoginView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showLoginView {
                LoginView()
            } else {
                Button("Login") {
                    self.showLoginView = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login View")
    }
}
```

[image: Changing the view without animation]

If you would like to animate this, so that the transition doesn't appear so abruptly, you can also do this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MasterView: View {
    @State var showLoginView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showLoginView {
                LoginView()
                    .animation(.spring())
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                Button("Login") {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showLoginView = true
                    }
                }.animation(.none)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login View")
    }
}
```

[image: Transition with animation]

Comment: @JensThomsen try the elaborated examples above

Comment: There's also .fullScreenCover option, using it the same the way as the modal sheet you explained.

Answer (score 5):

You can use navigation link instead button

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Title")
            .font(.headline)
        Image("myimage").clipShape(Circle())
        Text("mytext").font(.title)
        
        NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView()) {
           Image(systemName: "person.circle").imageScale(.large)
        }
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct Answer.

Comment: where is button?